# Casting the return from a java reflection method invocation

Tags: java, list, generics, reflection, hashmap

I am trying to write a generic method that will hash a list of objects based on calling a method through reflection. The idea is that the caller can specify which method will generate the keys for hashing. My problem is that I want to avoid the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation. So in essence I want to find a way to get method.invoke to return an object of Type T2 rather than Object. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public static <T1, T2> HashMap<T2, T1> hashFromList(
        List<T1> items_to_be_hashed,
        String method_name_to_use_to_generate_key) {
    HashMap<T2, T1> new_hashmap = new HashMap<>(items_to_be_hashed.size() + 5, 1);
    for (T1 object_to_be_hashed : items_to_be_hashed) {
        try {
            //Call the declared method for the key
            Method method = object_to_be_hashed.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(method_name_to_use_to_generate_key);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T2 key = (T2) method.invoke(object_to_be_hashed);
            new_hashmap.put(key, object_to_be_hashed);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return new_hashmap;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to avoid suppressing warnings and have a *true* cast (which would catch problems) is to know `T2` at execution time, which you can do via an extra parameter:

```
... hashFromList(List<T1> itemsToHash,
                 String generationMethod,
                 Class<T2> clazzT2)
```

You can then use [`Class.cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
T2 key = clazzT2.cast(method.invoke(objectToHash));
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm just interested in why you would want to use reflection over an interface? :)

Comment: @AlanFoster: Because that's what the question asks for? It's not about "should I use reflection" it's about "*given* that I'm using reflection, how can I cast safely?" - and I've chosen to answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce an interface that will return a key for you

```
// T1 = key, T2 = object type
public interface KeyGenerator<T1, T2> {
  T1 generateKey(T2 object);
}
```

And let your key generator implement that interface and then you can just change your header to be

```
public static <T1, T2> HashMap<T2, T1> hashFromList(
        List<T1> items_to_be_hashed,
        KeyGenerator<T2, T1> keyGenerator) {
```

And change the code to be

```
        T2 key = keyGenerator.generateKey(object_to_be_hashed);
```

This also means you can remove the NoSuchMethod exception, as you should have static typing on the object now (But obviously you can still get a NPE)

Hopefully this help; And it should be noted that generally reflection isn't always a good thing to put into your code! Use it wisely :)